# Discord.py Invalid arguments inside member.server_default_channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, discord, discord.py

My current code is

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    serverchannel = member.server.default_channel
    msg = "Wuss poppin', {0}. Welcome to {1}".format(member.mention, member.server.name)
    await client.send_message(member.server.default_channel, msg)`

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    serverchannel = member.server.default_channel
    msg = "Well. Cya, {0}!".format(member.mention)
    await client.send_message(serverchannel, msg)
```

As well as the other necessary lines (like `import discord` etc.) and other commands.

When a member joins or leaves, I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WillL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/WillL/Desktop/MemzBot-master/index.py", line 102, in on_member_join
    await client.send_message(member.server.default_channel, msg)
  File "C:\Users\WillL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1145, in send_message
    channel_id, guild_id = yield from self._resolve_destination(destination)
  File "C:\Users\WillL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 289, in _resolve_destination
    raise InvalidArgument(fmt.format(destination))
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Destination must be Channel, PrivateChannel, User, or Object. Received NoneType
```

I don't understand why, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Default channels no longer exist](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/change-log#breaking-change-default-channels). This means 2 things:

1. `server.default_channel` may return a NoneType.
2. Trying to send a message to `server` may raise `discord.NotFound`.

These cases will happen on any servers created after August 3rd, or any servers who have deleted their "default" channel.

You need to either choose a channel yourself, or ask the server to set a channel for the welcome message. You can still attempt to send to the server, but make sure you have a fall back option if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Default channels are not a thing anymore.