# Discord: How to get channel object where new member joined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to make a bot that send a message to new comer at the channel.
I'm using discord.py.

------------next day-------------------

Firstly, Thank you three people!(sorry for bad English). I studied a lot.

But unfortunately, I've found "member.server.defaul_channel"(which must have been this question's answer) no longer exist with this url:
[Discord.py Invalid arguments inside member.server_default_channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673995/discord-py-invalid-arguments-inside-member-server-default-channel?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Then, how to send a mention to the channel where new comer appears now?

1, I know a way that is to specity the channel name.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    server = member.server
    channel = [channel for channel in client.get_all_channels() if channel.name == 'WRITE_YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME!!'][0]
    message = 'hello {}, welcome to {}'.format(member.mention, server.name)
    await client.send_message(channel, message)
```

2, but I would like to know more universal way. Such as to use "default_channel". Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `on_member_join` event.

The following will send a message to the "general" channel every time a member joins a server.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    for channel in member.server.channels:
        if channel.name == 'general':
            await client.send_message(channel, 'Message to send when member joins')
```

If you want to check some other channel property instead of the name, then check the following documentation.

http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Channel

Note that I've tried using `channel.is_default` but this always returns `False`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can send a private message with your advice! And I'm sorry, I had wanted to know how to send mention on default ch. But thank you for your advice, I tried it and I could study!

Comment: I've updated my answer. The code now sends a message to a specified channel

Answer (score 0):

Members don't really join channels, they join servers.  Something like

```
@client.event
async def on_server_join(member):
    server = member.server
    default channel = server.default_channel
    message = ''Hello {}, welcome to {}'.format(member.mention, server.name)'
    await client.send_message(default_channel, message)
```

Would send a message on the default channel of the server whenever someone joins.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I tried it and error appears. "discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Destination must be Channel, PrivateChannel, User, or Object. Received NoneType"

Comment: I found an answer?(defaul_channel no longer exist)
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673995/discord-py-invalid-arguments-inside-member-server-default-channel

Comment: @shshsh12 Do you know which channel you want to send the message to?  Channels also have an order so you could try sending it to the "top" channel.

Answer (score 0):

The API has changed a little. This should work now:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    for channel in client.get_all_channels():
        if channel.name == 'general':
            await channel.send(
                f'Hi {member.mention}, Message to send when member joins')
```