# How to send a message to another server from my server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, discord.py

I need help with this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient

bot = commands.Bot(";")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def sendm(member, sv, ch, *, msg):
    serverd = member.server.id("{0}".format(sv))
    channel = member.server.get_channel("{0}".format(ch))
    await bot.send_message(serverd, channel, msg)
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

error list:

[image]

what I entered in a discord server:

```
;sendm 411576459077877783 general test
```

Hosting with Raspberry Pi 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the context, which means that the first argument is going to be a `Context` object, not a `Member`. As long as the message contains the channel id, you don't need anything else.

```
@bot.command()
async def sendm(ch, *, msg):
    channel = bot.get_channel(ch)
    if channel:
        await bot.send_message(channel, msg)
    else:
        await bot.say('I can't find that channel')
```

Comment: You can send messages to *some* servers.  Discord servers used to come with a default channel, which is where your  message would go if you tried to message the server.  New Discord servers ([After August of last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673995/discord-py-invalid-arguments-inside-member-server-default-channel)) no longer have a default channel, so messaging those servers isn't possible.  At this point, it's best to assume you can only message channels (those channels can be any channel the bot can access, even across servers).

Comment: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'message'`

Comment: a problem is ctx

Comment: The traceback should tell you the line of code that is raising the exception.  What is it?

Comment: You're not passing the context.  `@bot.command(pass_context=True)`

Comment: tell me how to get list of connected servers names